# Virtual machine on Azure DNS ping doesn't work in win server 2012

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

I try to setup a virtual machine in Azure service I create new virtual machine with win server 2012 I set a IIS default application pool when I try to connect to localhost I get my welcome page and everything is ok.

The problem is to connect from outside when I ping to DNS name or PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS I get time out. When I try nslookup I get my correct IP.
Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable Ping(ICMP) on Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783628/how-to-enable-pingicmp-on-azure)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Virtual Machines doesn't support ICMP. The Ping uses the ICMP protocol. You can only get through only TCP or UDP based traffic, provided you open the specified endpoint ( Ports ).

Try someother alternative to confirm the application's Heartbeat ( Up & Running ) like default http page by tools like Pingdom, if that is your intention.